# First movie where the Bald Eagle's cry is dubbed as Red-Tailed Hawk cry?

Tags: first-appearance, cinema-history, sound-effects, foley

[As](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stock_sound_effect) [noted](http://www.hollywood.com/movies/most-overused-sound-effects-in-hollywood-60409798/) [pretty](http://soundandthefoley.com/2013/05/08/hunting-time-red-tailed-hawk/) [much](http://listverse.com/2009/09/25/top-10-movie-sound-effects-we-all-recognize/) [everywhere](http://www.npr.org/templates/story/story.php?storyId=156187375), the Bald Eagle (*Haliaeetus Ieucocephalus*) we hear in movies is, like most things, a result of movie magic. In real life, they should like they are chirping with something stuck in their throat, like a dolphin. The real sound is attributed as the Red-Tailed Hawk (*Buteo jamaicensis*). In fact, pretty much any bird of prey is given the same sound, not just the Bald Eagle.

Where did this trend/cliche/trope first appear? In a Documentary? A TV Show/Cartoon? Or Movie?

Comment: This may go all the way back to Jack Foley (1891-1967) Whew! ☺ I would start looking at Westerns in the fifties.

Comment: The godfather of modern audio production